# How to get output of PowerShell's Get-WmiObject in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi, get-wmiobject

I need to get which network interface is connected to which network. I found that this information is accessible in MSFT_NetConnectionProfile. Unfortunatelly I cannot access it directly from C# ([I get `ManagementException: Provider load failure` on computer where it should run](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72183364/7007908)) but when I access it from PowerShell, it works. Then my idea is to run PowerShell command from C# but I cannot get the result.

```cs
using System.Management.Automation;

string command = "Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/StandardCimv2 -Class MSFT_NetConnectionProfile | Select-Object -Property InterfaceAlias, Name";

PowerShell psinstance = PowerShell.Create();
psinstance.Commands.AddScript(command);
var results = psinstance.Invoke();

foreach (var psObject in results)
{
    /* Get name and interfaceAlias */
}
```

The code runs without errors but results are empty. I tried even adding `Out-File -FilePath <path-to-file>` with relative and absolute file path but no file was created. I even tried old `>> <path-to-file>` but without luck. When I added `Out-String` then there was one result but it was empty string.

When I tested the commands directly in PowerShell then it worked. Is there a way how to get it in C#?

Comment: Isn't just `psinstance.AddScript(command);` instead of `psinstance.Commands.AddScript(command);` ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon It is possible, I think that I tried both ways but both failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PS commands must be constructed in a builder-pattern fashion.
Additionally, in PS Core the Get-WmiObject has been replaced by the Get-CimInstance CmdLet.

The following snippet is working on my env:

```
var result = PowerShell.Create()
                       .AddCommand("Get-CimInstance")
                       .AddParameter("Namespace", "root/StandardCimv2")
                       .AddParameter("Class", "MSFT_NetConnectionProfile")
                       .Invoke();
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, I just had to install `Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK` package. Without it I got `System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The 'Get-CimInstance' command was found in the module 'CimCmdlets', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module CimCmdlets'.`